# How to mock Calendar.getInstance for Java Testing using Mockito?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have a piece of code to test -

```
public class Test {

    public List<Long> getListExpiryTime(long time){
        List<Long> tempList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        tempList.add(getExpiryTime(time));
        return tempList;
    }


    private long getExpiryTime(long time) {
        long currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        return time - currentTime / 1000;
    }

}
```

I want to test whether the List returned has a certain value after I give an input time and we mock `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();`. How exactly do I do this? I prefer to do this using Mockito

Answer (score 0):

Calendar.getInstance is a static method and cannot be mocked with Mockito. PowerMockito could be of help but I strongly suggest to move away from Calendar and use the new time APIs from java.time. Your business component get a Clock injected that you can easily mock with Mockito.

Answer (score -1):

Create a method e.g. `getCurrentTime()` which only returns `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();` in a new class like `Helper`.

Then you can mock this method like this:

```
Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
date.set(...)
Mockito.when(helperMock.getCurrentTime()).thenReturn(date);
```